# Segmentation fault in Lua program with condition variable

Tags: lua, pthreads, luajit

I wrote the following simple Lua program to test condition variables with [POSIX threads in Lua](https://luapower.com/pthread):

```
local pthread = require 'pthread'

local cond = pthread.cond()
local mutex = pthread.mutex()
local ready = false

first = pthread.new(
    function()
        print('starting first')
        mutex:lock()
        print('first got lock')
        while not ready do
            cond:wait(mutex)
        end
        mutex:unlock()
        print('first continuing')
    end
)

second = pthread.new(
    function()
        print('starting second')
        mutex:lock()
        print('second got lock')
        ready = true
        cond:signal()
        mutex:unlock()
        print('second continuing')
    end
)

first:join()
second:join()

mutex:free()
cond:free()
```

Under luajit 2.1.0-beta1 on Ubuntu Trusty, this usually runs as expected, with output:

```
$ luajit condition.lua
starting first
first got lock
starting second
second got lock
second continuing
first continuing
```

However, sometimes (often) it crashes with a seg fault.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you link luajit with phthread library?

Comment: you try use same lua_State from several threads. You can not do this

Comment: @moteus OK, so how can two threads share a mutex or a condition variable?  
Luajit was installed by Torch; how can I determine whether it was linked with the pthread library?

Comment: First. You have to use different state in thread.On Windows you can use e.g. named mutexes. And use OpenMutex function. Or you can write some C library to be able share data across states. You can pass them as arguments https://github.com/moteus/lua-llthreads2/blob/master/test/test_threads_ex_arg.lua. Or you can use some type of connection e.g. TCP. I like use ZeroMQ.